# Semiconductor law of mass action

Tags: semiconductor-physics

When studying semiconductors, one would surely encounter the law of mass action for semiconductors:

$n \cdot p = n_i^2$

And I've found a variety of different explanations for it, but none was actually satisfying. Some sources say that this has to be valid in order for the semiconductor to be globally neutral, but I don't really see how you can get to that formula with that.
Most of the sources instead say that it comes directly from the law of mass action in chemistry. Now, I'm not an expert in chemistry (and I don't really care how you come up with that in that field), but again, I don't see how from that law in chemistry you can end up with $n \cdot p = n_i^2$ for a semiconductor.

I've seen a couple related SE questions, but none seem to solve the issue. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: All you need is that there is a dynamic balance incorporating some way to make carriers (electron gets from the valence band to the conduction band somehow, making a free electron and a hole), and some way to have electrons and holes recombine.  Any deviation of $np > n_{i}^{2}$ greater than zero, and recombination exceeds generation, and similarly any deviation of $np < n_{i}^{2}$ causes generation to exceed the recombination rate until dynamic equilibrium is restored. This is all you need (and, yes, [OH-][H+] is a constant is, well, the exact same thing).

Comment: Fun fact: mass action only applies to nondegenerate semiconductors. Once you have degenerate doping then you have $np<n_i^2$. Any explanation that requires it to always apply must therefore be incorrect. (such as arguments about charge neutrality, which are obviously wrong anyway)